# Why did my p-value equals 0 and statistic equals 1 when I use ks test in python?

Tags: python, statistics, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov

Thanks to anyone who have a look first.

My codes are :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kstest
data=[31001, 38502, 40842, 40852, 43007, 47228, 48320, 50500, 54545, 57437, 60126, 65556, 71215, 78460, 81299, 96851, 106472, 108398, 118495, 130832, 141678, 155703, 180689, 218032, 222238, 239553, 250895, 274025, 298231, 330228, 330910, 352058, 362993, 369690, 382487, 397270, 414179, 454013, 504993, 518475, 531767, 551032, 782483, 913658, 1432195, 1712510, 2726323, 2777535, 3996759, 13608152]
x=np.array(data)
test_sta=kstest(x, 'norm')
print(test_sta)
```

The result of kstest is KstestResult(statistic=1.0, pvalue=0.0). Is there anything wrong with the code or the data is just not normal at all?

Comment: I am not a statistics person, but in general it helps if you explain why the answer you  get is incorrect or what you expect an answer to be.

Comment: The data is not normal. I put mode='asymp` and got p-value ca 7.5e-44. It is HIGHLY unprobable data follows normal distribution

Comment: @RufusVS I am not sure why my code goes wrong but I expect the p_value and statistic to be something with long decimal places, something like KstestResult(statistic=0.10791938765494785, pvalue=0.1810189923046682)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux  Thanks so much. So, do you mean that the p-value=0.0 is solely because the data is really not normal?

Comment: Yes. Basically, with 0 probability this sample of data might come from normal distribution. Or with probability 7.5e-44 sample might come from normal distribution.

Comment: And casting data to N(0,1) standard normal, I've got p-value of 6.8e-7, which means it is very unprobable to get this data set as sample from normal distribution.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Got it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used this before, but I think you're testing whether your data is standard-normal (i.e. mean=0, variance=1)

plotting a histogram shows it to be much closer to a log-normal.  I'd therefore do:

```
x = np.log(data)
x -= np.mean(x)
x /= np.std(x)
kstest(x, 'norm')
```

which gives me a test statistic of 0.095 and a p-value of 0.75, confirming that we can't reject that it's not log-normal.

a good way to check this sort of thing is to generate some random data (from a known distribution) and see what the test gives you back.  for example:

```
kstest(np.random.normal(size=100), 'norm')
```

gives me p-values near 1, while:

```
kstest(np.random.normal(loc=13, size=100), 'norm')
```

gives me p-values near 0.

a log-normal distribution just means that it's normally distributed after log transforming.  if you really want to test against a normal distribution, you'd just not log transform the data, e.g:

```
x = np.array(data, dtype=float)
x -= np.mean(x)
x /= np.std(x)
kstest(x, 'norm')
```

which gives me a p-value of 7e-7, indicating that we can reliably reject the hypothesis that it's normally distributed.

Comment: Thanks so much first! But I am still confused. Is there a way that I can compared my data to the normal distribution instead of log normal distribution?

Comment: @CyndiaChen have updated my answer.  I'd suggest following though some introductions to statistics on how the common distributions are related

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.